# C++ Fixed Size Container to Store Most Recent Values

Tags: c++, stack, queue, containers

I would like to know what the most suitable data structure is for the following problem in C++

I am wanting to store 100 floats ordered by recency. So when I add (push) a new item the other elements are moved up one position. Every time an event is triggered I receive a value and then add it to my data structure.

When the number of elements reaches 100, I would like to remove (pop) the item at the end (the oldest).

I want to able to iterate over all the elements and perform some mathematical operations on them.

I have looked at all the standard C++ containers but none of them fulfill all my needs. What's the easiest way to achieve this with standard C++ code?

Comment: [std::queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) is good for this problem i think

Comment: I can't iterate over the whole std::queue very easily - I want to take a weighted average of all the items.

Comment: @CalG Why you can't do? each time you insert/Pop into queue update avg value.

Comment: @Shan floating-point errors accumulation.

Comment: If you just need average, why don't go with a running sum and running average? O(1) space and O(1) time complexity :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a *circular buffer*. You can use [Boost's implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html) or make your own by allocating an array, and keeping track of the beginning and end of the used range. This boils down to doing indexing modulo 100.

Comment: Will you be able to handle duplicates. I mean if there is a number say 20 being used again and again, whole buffer would be having 20 all over. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Abhinav why, yes. OP doesn't mention special treatment for duplicates.

Comment: I actually used std::deque to solve my problem                                                 if (myDeque.size() > 100){ myDeque.pop_front() }                                         However a circular buffer would have been appropriate

Comment: Quentin , IMHO if a problem is not specified, we go for general solution. In that sense a circular buffer is wrong answer.
@CalG , please update your question if yours is a specific case (I bet it cant be) otherwise this is too specific solution and therefore not correct in all situations!

Comment: @Abhinav I don't get it. If you store the same value several times, the general solution is not to be smart about it and just store the thing 20 times. If you need to prune duplicates, *then* you will need a more specific solution. Nowhere in the OP is it made case of duplicate values.

Comment: A simple question would be: Why one needs MRU? Because the items would be needed (search may be). In this case last 100 items and items would mean 100 unique. A cache would be a perfect example of this. If 100 items in a MRU cache in which if an element is used 100 times, it wouldn't discard rest of the elements from cache.

Comment: @Abhinav you're extrapolating. But if we're at it then my guess at the context would rather be "display a smoothed measured value by averaging the 100 latest samples", as OP mentions taking the average of all the values — which would be skewed were you to ignore multiple occurences of the same value.

Comment: @Quentin Yes the solution is perfect but overly complicated. I would go with a running sum and running average in that case. O(1) space and O(1) time complexity :-)

Comment: @Abhinav that'd be perfect, if not for the floating-point error accumulation.

Comment: that can be taken care of by using double precision for running average to take care of these.

Comment: @Abhinav *maybe*. Maybe not. Anyway, this is off-topic again, fulfilling OP's specifications closely ought to be it.

Answer (score 3):

Without creating your own or using a library, `std::vector` is the most efficient standard data structure for this. Once it has reached its maximum size, there will be no more dynamic memory allocations. The cost of moving up 100 floats is trivial compared to the cost of dynamic memory allocations. (This is why `std::list` is a slow data structure for this). There is no push_front function for vector. Instead you have to use `v.insert(v.begin(), f)`

Of course this assumes what you are doing is performance-critical, which it probably isn't. In that case I would use `std::deque` for more convenient usage.

Comment: Why there will be no more dynamic memory allocations, once `std::vector` has reached its max size? As you know, we can `push_back` as many times as possible and the underlying memory grows up infinitely(reallocation). How `std::vector` can be a container the OP wants? OP wants a fixed-sized container, retaining only the recent N elements.

Comment: @starriet Once the vector has reached the highest size it ever will during the run of the program, it won't allocate any more times. If you push_back beyond this size, then it wasn't at its maximum size..

Comment: Thanks. By the way, the complexity of `std::vector::insert` is linear(O(n)), so I think it's not very "performance-critical". Isn't it possible to make a faster data structure than O(n), for a fixed-sized container?

Comment: @starriet The problem is limited to 100 floats, which is small for a computer. If the upper limit were unbounded, I wouldn't suggest this. Other containers have front insert with better complexity, but could perform more dynamic memory allocations or have poorer memory locality and can make overall performance worse. You have to consider the complexities and costs of all parts of the solution, and not just 1 of the functions that will be called. A circular buffer based on a contiguous array, as suggested in the accepted answer, is better solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw that you need to iterator over them. Use a `list`.

Your basic function would look something like this

```
void addToList(int value){
    list100.push_back(value);
    if(list100.size() > 100){
        list100.pop_front();
    }
}
```

Iterating over them is easy as well:

```
for(int val : list100){
    sum += val;
}
// Average, or whatever you need to do
```

Obviously, if you're using something besides `int`, you'll need to change that. Although this adds a little bit more functionality than you need, it's very efficient since it's a doubly linked list.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Comment: Yes, but how do I iterate over all the values and take an average?

Comment: Nope. Thats incorrect IMHO. what about same element is always pushed 100 times. your queue will have only 1 element in 100 locations.

Comment: i think a circular buffer is the better fit since he has the requirement of a fixed size.

Comment: A list is particularly ill-suited for this job. You need neither the extensibility, nor the O(1) middle insertion, and traversal will be hurt by the fragmentation of your data.

Comment: I agree on the circular buffer. I was sticking with `std::`, as the OP requested. How would it hurt traversal? An array goes from memory location to memory location just like a list. I suppose it COULD be affected by how the memory is paged, but with 100 values, I don't see that being an issue.

Comment: Granted, on small data sets the difference won't be noticeable, but that's not to say we shoud give into premature pessimisation. An array lays its elements contiguously and is the most cache-friendly structure as nothing is wasted. A list, on the other hand, has no requirement to fit neatly on a cache line at all. And even if by pure luck all your nodes end up being side-by-side, you're wasting at best 80% of the cache space for the pointers, and the CPU needs to repeteadly jump through them instead of merely incrementing a register. `std::list` is for flexibility, not speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either std::array, std::dequeue, std::list or std::priority_queue

Answer (score -1):

A MAP (std::map) should be able to solve your requirement. Use Key as the object and value as the current push number nPusheCount which gets incremented whenever you add an element to map.
when adding a new element to map, if you have less than 100 elements, just add the number to the MAP as key and nPushCount as the value.
If you have 100 elements already, check if the number exists in map already and do following:

1. If the number already exists in map, then add the number as key and nPushCount as value;
2. If doesnt, delete the number with lowest nPushCount as value and then add the desired number with updated nPushCount.

Comment: This is way too complicated a solution for a fairly simple problem