# Container of fixed size where items exist within it according to their demand

Tags: data-structures, containers

I'm trying to implement a container with the following characteristics:

1. The container has a fixed size `n`.
2. When an item is inserted into the container, if the item is in the data structure it will be **moved** to the front of it. If not it will be **inserted** to the front of the data structure, but the last item at the back of the container will be removed to respect the fixed size `n`.
3. Building on for 2, it will be required to check whether an item exists in this container in order to know whether to **insert** or **move** an item in the container.

The reasoning behind this container, is to keep frequently accessed items in the container. The cost of **inserting** a new item into the container is large thus it is in my interest to keep it in the container for as long as it is in demand.

Is there a container/data structure that exists that achieves something similar to what I've described? If not can you provide any advice on how to implement it? I'm using C++ but any examples or pseudocode will be equally appreciated.

Edit:

I suppose what I need is a kind of queue with no duplicate items. The queue needs to be searched to see if an item exists within it, and if so moves it to the front of the queue. A fixed size isn't that difficult to adhere to (just check the size before insertion and if it will go over remove the last item in the queue). Basically this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026193/c-fixed-size-container-to-store-most-recent-values) but not allowing any duplicates in the container, and also fast search capabilities to check if an item is within it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following the requirements you gave but this seems like it can be implemented as as a double-ended queue (C++ deque or Java Deque). Each time an element is accessed implies a linear search (can't be avoided), then this element is moved to the front (constant time), and the last element removed (also constant time). This should result that the most frequently accessed elements move to the front of the queue over time, decreasing the real-time cost of a linear search.

A double-ended queue can be implemented as a ring-buffer or as a doubly-linked-list. Since you stated a fixed number of elements, the ring buffer seems like the better option.

However, I can't vouch for the implementations of C++ or Java deque.. you may look at the source code to see if its backed as an array or a linked node structure.

Maybe wrap a priority queue with elements having a last-accessed-time attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You may check Splay Tree. If you do some operation on element X, that element move to root.